# Check if variable have already been appended

Tags: jquery, if-statement, append

Got a problem.
In the following fiddle I have tried to exemplify how I wish to check for if the variable "htmlstring" has already been appended, and if so, then not to append another. On the other hand if it haven't been appended, ofcourse append it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lc5gdvge/6/

How do I make this work?
All in all, what I need is a if-else code, that will check for previous appended variable. If none has been appended it will append, if the container already contains the appended variable "htmlstring" then it ofcourse shouldn't append a new one.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('.outerdiv').click(function () {
    var htmlstring = $(this).contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType == 3;}).text()
    if ($('.innerdiv').innerhtml( jQuery.inArray(htmlstring, arr))){ /*this line is the problem*/
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('div.innerdiv').append(htmlstring);}

 })
 });
```

Comment: Where is `arr` being defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `length` to find if any content is present like

```
var checkContent =  $(this).find('div.innerdiv').html().length;
if(checkContent> 0){
//contents are present
}
```

**NOTE:** You have a semi-colon missing in your

```
$('.outerdiv').click(function () {

});// missing semi-colon. Its good to use one
```

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that the container being checked also contains alot of different tags in the real project. Does this make any difference?

Comment: then use  $(this).find('div.innerdiv').children('your desired tag').length

Comment: No, no. I don't need to check for the tag, I just wanted to know if your solution worked eventho the htmlstring was being appended to a container that ALSO contained alot of different tags. I've updated fiddle with a small example of an <i> element within the same container.

Comment: what exactly are you checking in jQuery.inArray(htmlstring, arr) ?

Comment: Tried checking whether the "htmlstring" had been appended to the selector.

Comment: You dont have to use inArray for that..did you try my solution, just check for the particular element you are tyring to search in a div and check its length

Comment: Problem is that the "htmlstring" differs in length. It's a variable of text retrieved from another source. It could have a length of 1 to infinite.

Comment: In that htmlstring, use find() function to find that particular element and then check its length

Comment: I will try it out later, the I'm advance